# Strange syntax for associating type with variable for occurrence typing

Tags: types, clojure, clojure-core.typed

In https://github.com/clojure/core.typed/wiki/User-Guide#occurrence-typing an example of occurrence typing is provided:

```
clojure.core.typed=> (cf (let [a (ann-form 1 Any)]
                           (cond
                            (symbol? a) a
                            (number? a) a)))
(U Sym Num nil)
```

Why exactly is `(ann-form 1 Any)` used? I guess it is a hacky/idiomatic way to set the type of `a` by annotating `1` and then setting `a` to that value, but I can't really understand why this is chosen syntax for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ann-form` just forgets type information about a particular expression.

Here we forget `1` is a `(Val 1)`, and consider it of type `Any` for the rest of the program. This way we can demonstrate how occurrence typing works with local bindings of type `Any`.

You can also write it with [clojure.core.typed/let](http://clojure.github.io/core.typed/#clojure.core.typed/let) like so:

```
(let [a :- Any, 1]
  (cond
    (symbol? a) a
    (number? a) a))
```

Comment: So just to clarify, the 1 is used by convention but could be any value? Why is it necessary to assign a value to `a` (and not just a type) for occurrence typing to work?

Comment: My colleague explained to me that a variable can't be declared without giving it a value, so ignore my Clojure n00b question. It all makes sense to me now (assuming I am right and 1 is only used by convention instead of any arbitrary value).

Comment: Yes, replace anything for 1. Changing the `let` to a `fn` and just passing the 1 might be a clearer example.